# Cannot install Microsoft Lync 2013 SDK (Preview)

Tags: lync-client-sdk

I am trying to install Lync 2013 preview from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30350

but I get an error that Lync 2013 isn't installed and I can download it from go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=248583 - which is a link to SDK preview documentation..

I have installed Lync 2013 Basic and the previous SDK installed without problems..

Any ideas?

Comment: It may not be relevant but you should probably not be using the Preview as the [actual SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36824) has been released.

Comment: thanks for the input.. It wasn't released at the moment in Denmark and I needed to try it to see if it had fixed my problem. But just for information my problem wasn't in the SDK but in the virtual setup.